# How to add a conversion using laravel media library from only one of the multiple uploaded images

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I'm uploading multiple images for a property and everything works well. The images and their conversions are uploaded successfully. However, a conversion is created for every image of a given property but I'd like to create a conversion only for the first image of the multiple uploads. How can I achieve that?

My controller logic

```
 foreach ($request->file('images') as $image) {
      $property->addMedia($image)->withResponsiveImages()->toMediaCollection();
    }
```

My model conversion logic

```
  public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
  {
    $this->addMediaConversion('small_thumb')
      ->width(300)
      ->height(200);
  }
```

Comment: `foreach ($request->file('images') as $k => $image) { if ($k === 0) { // stuff with conversions } else { // stuff without conversions } }` ?

Comment: What do you mean by stuff without conversions? Could you please elaborate on that with code if possible?